# How to properly mount a usb drive?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I am having trouble mounting my usb drive to my Rpi3. I followed this tutorial: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-add-usb-storage-to-the-raspberry-pi/

But, when I add files and restart my Rpi3 it automatically deletes the files I just created on it.

I am trying to use the extra storage for projects I want to build but it would difficult with the limited amount of storage I have on the sd card.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you edited your /etc/fstab to accept your disc on boot?

Comment: yeah i did this

LABEL=PIDRIVE1  /home/pi/pidrive   ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

Comment: What if you check in the mount dir what's in there? Even if you umount it. I believe there's something with the directory itself that has issues. so rmdir and mkdir commands could you try with.

Comment: The only thing in there is a lost+found dir

Comment: But when I use to mkdir command it works fine till i restart my pi then the folder or files get deleted or are left blank

Comment: Where is your mounting point?

Comment: my mounting point is "/home/pi/pidrive"

Comment: Try setting it in /media or /mnt. I've never tried mounting something else in a local dir than sshfs.

Comment: I have set it in both /media and /mnt but had the same problem

Comment: Can you Pastebin all your configurations and also put the whole link where it's at?

Comment: Where do I access my configurations? Im kind of new to using an RPi3

Comment: Use this style if it's ext4 filesystem in /etc/fstab: UUID=0f98bb17-b1a0-4166-b462-719b9ef27b9a /media/disc               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1 and change the '4166-b462-719b9ef27b9a' to the one that's yours. mkdir /media/disc (with or without sudo. Use sudo if it fails without it).

Comment: Run this command to get the UUID from the discs: blkid